# C# - UrlHistoryWrapper class - Not enough storage is available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070008)

Tags: c#, error-handling, comexception

I am getting values from a database, and trying to insert them into Internet Explorers history, using the UrlHistoryWrapper class. When I set the `for` conditions to something in the thousands, I will get this error, however, when I set the for condition to less than 100, it will run fine. I have checked the memory usage, and it should cause no problems. How can I make this code able to run, if chrome.URLs and firefox.URLs have thousands of values?

This is my code:

```
UrlHistoryWrapperClass urlHistory;
        UrlHistoryWrapperClass.STATURLEnumerator enumerator;
        List<STATURL> list = new List<STATURL>();
        urlHistory = new UrlHistoryWrapperClass();
        enumerator = urlHistory.GetEnumerator();
        bool display = false;
        chrome.GetHistory(display);
        for (int i = 0; i < chrome.URLs.Count; i++ )
        {
            URL url = chrome.URLs[i];
            urlHistory.AddHistoryEntry(url.url, url.title, ADDURL_FLAG.ADDURL_ADDTOHISTORYANDCACHE);
        }
        Firefox firefox = new Firefox();
        firefox.GetHistory(display:false);
        foreach (URL url in firefox.URLs)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(url.url);

            urlHistory.AddHistoryEntry(url.url, url.title, ADDURL_FLAG.ADDURL_ADDTOHISTORYANDCACHE);
        }
```

And this is my error:

> ******* *Exception Text* ********* 
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070008): Not enough
>   storage is available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070008)    at UrlHistoryLibrary.IUrlHistoryStg2.AddUrl(String
>   pocsUrl, String pocsTitle, ADDURL_FLAG dwFlags)    at
>   UrlHistoryLibrary.UrlHistoryWrapperClass.AddHistoryEntry(String
>   pocsUrl, String pocsTitle, ADDURL_FLAG dwFlags)    at
>   Namespace.IE.SyncIE() in C:\Users\Chris\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\TestURLGUI4\TestURLGUI4\URLHistory.cs:line 270    at
>   Namespace.Program.SyncAll() in C:\Users\Chris\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\TestURLGUI4\TestURLGUI4\URLHistory.cs:line 152    at
>   TestURLGUI2.Form1.button11_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\Chris\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\TestURLGUI4\TestURLGUI4\Form1.cs:line 247    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Edit:

Here is my new code:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < firefox.URLs.Count; i++ )
    {
        URL url = firefox.URLs[i];
        urlHistory.AddHistoryEntry(url.url, url.title, ADDURL_FLAG.ADDURL_ADDTOHISTORYANDCACHE);
        Thread.Sleep(3);
        form.label1.Text = i + "/" + firefox.URLs.Count;
      //  MessageBox.Show(url.url);
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
```

Now, with this code, I can go up to 8447 without getting this error, but then it gets thrown.

I had someone else try to do this, and this is what he said:

> Just tried your code and and it seems that there is a limit on the
>   number of the url records that can be added.   I did the following
>   steps.
>
> 1. In Internet Explorer, Clear the history of websites I've visited.
> 2. I tried your code.
> 3. Got a COMException (0x80070008): Not enough storage is available to process this command. The exception is thrown at record number 41021
>      for me (Windows 7, 64bit).
> 4. I tried your code again, and Got a very same exception. This time, No record have be added.   To add the url records again. I have
>      to clear the history of websites in Internet Explorer.   I could not
>      find a way to fix the problem.

For anyone who needs to know, the source code for the URLhistoryWrapper can be found on [this CodeProject project](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=7500).

Comment: I have heard of these types of Exceptions being "caused" by memory leaks and inappropriate usage of the OS's "temp" directory. Unfortunately, I have experienced similar problems and never found a solution.

Comment: Wasn't me LOL, I too would like like a solution to this problem. I'll counter it with an upvote. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution I found to work. U need to run the

```
foreach (URL url in firefox.URLs)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(url.url);

        urlHistory.AddHistoryEntry(url.url, url.title, ADDURL_FLAG.ADDURL_ADDTOHISTORYANDCACHE);
    }
```

and the chrome ones, etc, in another thread. Like this:

```
Thread testthread = new Thread(SynceFirefoxToIE);
        testthread.Name = "FirefoxToIESynceThread";
        testthread.Start();


    }

    public void SynceFirefoxToIE() 
    {
        foreach (URL url in firefox.URLs)
      {

         urlHistory.AddHistoryEntry(url.url, url.title, ADDURL_FLAG.ADDURL_ADDTOHISTORYANDCACHE);
      }

    }
```